# show multiple layers on geopandas.explore() with correct legend labels

Tags: python, geopandas

I read multiple `gpkg`-files and I want to see them all when I use `geopandas.explore()`

what I currently have is:

```
m = df1.explore(
                column='some_value1',
                tiles="CartoDB positron",
                cmap='RdYlGn')

m = df2.explore(m=m,
                column='some_value2',
                tiles="CartoDB positron",
                cmap='RdYlGn')

m = df3.explore(m=m,
                column='some_value3',
                tiles="CartoDB positron",
                cmap='RdYlGn')

m = df4.explore(m=m,
                column='avg_speed_nov_evn',
                tiles="CartoDB positron",
                cmap='RdYlGn')


folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)


m
```

but see the pic, I want to change the name of the layers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a name for each of the layers by adding the name to the explore function call:

> m = df1.explore(
> column='some_value1',
> tiles="CartoDB positron",
> cmap='RdYlGn',
> name='layer_name')